# Rails complicated relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following classes with relations defined as follow:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :clan
 has_one :found_clan,class: Clan,foreign_key: 'founder'
end

class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, primary_key: 'id', foreign_key: 'clan_id'
 belongs_to :founder,class: User,primary_key: 'founder'
end
```

User model has a field named: `clan_id`

Clan model has a field named: `founder`

What i would like its:

`user.found_clan` => resulting a clan object which has `user` as `founder`

`user.clan` => resulting a clan object pointed by users `clan_id`

`clan.founder` => resulting an user object which `clan.founder` points at

`clan.users` => resulting an array of all `users` who have `clan` pointed by `user.clan_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

1. The Rails association helpers take `class_name: 'Model'` as options, not `class: Model`.
2. You should name your founder column `founder_id`, not just `founder`
3. When you want to specify a table column for joins, you must use `foreign_key` on both sides of the relationship (not `primary_key`!)
4. For associations that stick to Rails' naming conventions, you do not need to supply the `primary_key` and `foreign_key` options (in this case `Clan has_many :users`)

This should work:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :clan
  has_one :clan_founded, class_name: 'Clan', foreign_key: 'founder_id'
end

class Clan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :founder, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'founder_id'
end
```